# Redirecting to another web-page with a redirection message

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, mobile

I have a use case where I want to redirect to a external link(xxx)on click of a button.

There are two ways for me to redirect to external page:
1) Show the redirection message   “You are being redirected to xxx site” for some seconds(say 1.5s )and then redirect to xxx link.
2) While the external page is loading, I want to show a redirection message: “You are being redirected to xxx site” and then redirect to xxx link.

[image: Mock]

a)For achieving the first case, I am observing, when I click on cross button on embedded browser on the 3p website, I am redirected to the page with temporary redirection message.Expected behaviour is redirection to my initial webpage.This is the JS I am executing on the click on the button

```
            document.body.innerHTML = 'You are being redirected...';
            setTimeout("location.href = 'https://www.icicibank.com/online-services/clicktopay/index.page';",1500);
```

Any pointers will be helpful.

b)Any pointers to achieve the second case where the page is being loaded in the background.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what was the problem with case 1.  And I don't think the case 2 is possible unless the target site supports such functionality.

Comment: @Aditya For Case 1, In the embedded browser, when I am clicking on cross/back button, I am being redirected to the temporary redirection message.Expected behaviour is redirection to my initial webpage.

Comment: That is probably happenning because you are replacing innerHTML of the body with the message. So, the browser lost track of the original content. Try to display the message in a way that the content is not lost.

Comment: @Aditya Any pointers on the same?